# Can I alternate row shading but also give columns colors in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, colors

I'm fairly inexperienced with excel, but I know how to both color a column in a table and also setup a table with alternating rows. What I am trying to do is have alternating row shading in a table with headers while also coloring the columns different color tones to help them stand out as well. Is there a way to do this as one large table rather than separate small tables for each column?

Comment: Created a table with the regular row alternation, Tried just coloring columns over top of that, but that merely changed that column to a solid color regardless of tone. I went into the custom table settings but it only supports alternating rows or columns being different colors as well as first and last of anything (row, column, cell).

Comment: When I tried what you described, I experienced the same thing and couldn't find another way to do it. So, I'm not sure it can be done the way you want. Sorry I am no help. Maybe someone else here will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this would be messing around with the opacity of the colours, I'm pretty certain you can't do that.  Even if you could I'm not sure it would have the effect you are after.

Perhaps you could format the rows with the colours you want and use the border styles to make the columns stand out?

Comment: Good point about using cell borders for the column as a whole to make it pop.